# How do I hide buttons like the "delete" one in a node form?

Tags: forms

Consider I created a CCK node called *assignment*, and I am adding assignments with that.

There is a field called "published" with a check box. If the assignment is published, then it should not be deleted.

My problem is how I can hide the "delete" button if the assignment is published. By using prefix and suffix and using `display: none;` in `hook_form_alter()` will work, but it is not the secured way. I need something in the Drupal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the below to hide the buttons in form alter.

> unset($form['buttons']['delete']);

Comment: In this way it can be possible to delete content in Content Overview Page.

Comment: But the delete button is hide and what is the possible case to delete the content in the overview page. Your suggestion confused me :(

Comment: Removing a form field in that way is never the suggested way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_access/6).
Super simple example will hide button "Delete" automaticaly and disallow deletion of some nodes in any other places in Drupal.

Important note:

> The administrative account (user ID #1) always passes any access check, so this hook is not called in that case.

```
function MYMODULE_access($op, $node, $account) {
   if ($op == 'delete') {
      if ($node->something != 'something') {
          return FALSE;
      }
   }
}
```

For Drupal 7 there is [hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_access/7) for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 each content type has a permission (on the permissions page at yourdomain.com/admin/people/permissions) called "Delete own content" which you can use as long as the user isn't an administrator because admins have all permissions enabled by default.

If you need to disable it for the admin user as well there's a module called [Jammer](http://drupal.org/project/jammer).

Answer (score 0):

use unset($form['actions']['delete']);